# Male hypogonadism and late bloomers

Tags: testosterone, growth-hormones

Are the teenagers diagnosed with male hypogonadism referred to as 'late bloomers'? For example, a 17M with not fully developed genitals and height of 5'6" and paternal height 5'8" and 5'0". Is he expected to grow in genitals and adult height after the T levels are boosted up?(Current level-365ng/dL)